# How to install 'tensorflow_examples' in colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I run [Image segmentation in Tensorflow Core tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation) in Google Colab.
When running

```bash
!pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git
```

get an error

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git
  Cloning https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-u7_jdkn8
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git /tmp/pip-req-build-u7_jdkn8
  Resolved https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git to commit e3849ccb6d981aad311f0174281c8575d5e21646
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I want to use 'tensorflow_examlples' like

```py
from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
!apt remove git -y # remove any degraded git module
!apt-get install git -y && git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git # Install git first, then clone.
```

> refer to: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/60106#issuecomment-1487638835

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/examples')
```

> refer to: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/60106#issuecomment-1511149579

then import 'pix2pix'

```py
from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix
```